# How do I use access token for the Facebook Opengraph javascript SDK api requests?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

This is my first attempt at using the Facebook API. I am building a website, on which I have a ratings and references page, where I would like to include FB ratings.

First of all with regards to procedure, I am not sure if I should be building a Facebook App for this, and using the App token access, or if I can use the User or Page access token. And can I do this without exposing the access token or app ID?

Testing the different user tokens in the ["Graph Api Explorer"](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/) seems to allow responses in all three ways for ratings. So why would I need an App?

```
function facebookLoad () {
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
        appId      : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        xfbml      : true,
        version    : 'v2.5'
        });

            FB.api(
            '/website.com',
            'GET',
            {"fields":"ratings"},
            function(response) {
                // Insert your code here
                console.log(response);

                }
            );
    };

    (function(d, s, id){
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js';
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
}
```

The script so far works, in the sense that I recieve a response object. The object is however an error object with the following message:

```
...
message: "An access token is required to request this resource."
type: "OAuthException"
....
```

Clearly I need to use an Access token, but which one? And how? All I want to do is extract the ratings from the response, so I can place them on the webpage.

**UPDATE:**

Thanks for the comments guys, put me in the right direction(I think). I realise I'm already getting downvotes, but thought I would update anyway, as I haven't found a really good answer yet anywhere else.

```
function facebookLoad () {
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
        appId      : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        xfbml      : true,
        cookie     : true,
        version    : 'v2.5'
        });

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse){

            console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
            FB.api('/me/accounts', 
                function(response){ 

                    var p_accessToken = response.data[0].access_token; 
                    var p_name = response.data[0].name; 

                    FB.api(
                        '/me?access_token='+p_accessToken+'',
                        'GET',
                        {"fields":"about,ratings"},
                        function(response) 
                        {     
                        /* console.log(JSON.stringify(response)); */
                        console.log(response);
                        }
                    );
                });

                } else {
                    console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
                }
            });

    };

    (function(d, s, id){
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js';
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
}
```

Using the updated code above I'm now able to retrieve the data-object with ratings, using a temporary page-token, and making the call using getLoginStatus, after using a temporary login button

`<div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="medium" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="false"`**`data-scope="manage_pages,publish_pages"`**`></div>`

to sign in an admin with `manage_pages` and `publish_pages` permissions, by adding them to the data-scope.

I'm still struggling with the process though. In order for getLoginStatus to execute succesfully I need the page access token to be permanent, so I can remove the login button from the site again.

Currently I need to login everytime the cookie is reset, which is fine for testing, but not for production. Reading the documentation section [Extending Page Access Tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension#extendingpagetokens) it seems getting a permanent token is possible.

So how can I exchange the temporary token, for a permanent one, safely, client-side, without a server-side application?

I'm thinking I should be able to do this somehow, using the temporary user token manually once.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

Comment: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: Exposing your app id is no problem – but exposing your app secret or a page or app access token in client-side code is an absolute no. So if you need this kind of token, then you should make the request server-side.

Comment: Thanks guys for the comments, I updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after figuring out what I needed was a page access token, I gave up trying to do this client-side, realising server-side makes more sense, at least security wise.

```
<?php 
define('FACEBOOK_SDK_V4_SRC_DIR', __DIR__ .'/../src/Facebook/');
require_once __DIR__ .'/../src/Facebook/autoload.php';

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => 'app_id_string',
  'app_secret' => 'app_secret_string',
  'default_access_token' => 'page_access_token_string',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
]);

$response = $fb->get('/me?fields=ratings');
var_dump($response);
?>
```

I simply used the [Graph Api Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/) to extend the token permanently.

I found [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_batch_request) part of the documentation on batch-requests particularly usefull.

On a personal note, I can't believe I had to spend 4 days braining this. I really didn't like the facebook documentation to be honest, but then, it may be that I'm simply stupid.